# Flutter/Dart & Firebase Error Messages & Codes

Tags: firebase, error-handling, dart, flutter, future

I am implementing Firebase Auth into my Flutter app. How do I access error codes or user friendly error messages from Firebase? Is this available yet?

For example, on iOS you can get the `localisedDescription` from an error.

In Dart I have a `onError:` and `catchError` Futures which return an error object, but don't appear to have the relevant associated information.

Comment: `print`, `debugPrint`

Answer (score 2):

it is available.  the problem is that the catchError value is not an object, so you can't loop thru its keys. print/debugPrint just outputs the values without giving you any clue how to reference only one of them.

it has getter methods - code, message, and...details. 'details' is the human-readable result, but it's not documented on the firebase_auth flutter example. do this:

```
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e.details); // code, message, details
});
```